# Magento 2.3.1 Multiple categories showing active, How to remove duplicate active class?

Tags: magento2, category, topmenu

In my instance, I have updated Magento 2.3.1 from 2.3.0.

**I have an issue that more than one categories are showing active on each page.**

**it shows randomly selected more than one categories.**

How could I solve this?

If anyone has any idea about it please share.